# Annotate github issues on application GUI

Tags: github, issue-tracking

So I am working on a small personal project with two people, and we are managing it using github project with issues as tasks and bugs.

Due to limited resources we all spend time finding bugs. I want to make sure that my team members don't spend time testing the same bugs and reporting them.

Therefore I want to know if there is any app/chrome extension that can show the issues submitted on top of my application's GUI just like bugherd is doing.

[image: bug-herd-anotations]
See the full video on the link below.

https://player.vimeo.com/video/39621566?autoplay=1

Comment: (a) Asking us to find or recommend off-site resources is off-topic. (b) What if there are actually two or more issues relating to a single component? You'd probably be better off simply telling your people to search before they report new issues, which is a common best practice.

Comment: a) didn't know that. thanks b) the purpose of annotating bugs is actually solving that problem, because you will see circled dots on the component so you already know there is a bug associated with that component that already exists.